# How to fix "Bundler 2 requires RubyGems 2.5 or later"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am a newbie and using Ruby on Rails, I am stuck with this problem.
I am trying to install Ruby on Rails, and when I am trying to check rails's version with "rails -v", it gave me this message:

```
Bundler 2 requires RubyGems 2.5 or later. Either install bundler 1 or update to a support RubyGems version
```

I tried to update the gem with `gem update --system` but it gave me this message:

```
ERROR: While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError) SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed.
```

(https://api.rubygemsorg/specs.4.8.gz)

When I check my gem version with `gem --version`, it gives me `2.3.0`.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: did you tried this [gist](https://gist.github.com/luislavena/f064211759ee0f806c88)

Comment: I tried download the lastest version 3.0.3 gem from this, and used this command to install it : "gem install --force --local *.gem", it said to me that "1 gem installed", but when I checked it still 2.3.0 so nothing change. Could you please help me ? Thank you so much.

Comment: can you update you're question with `bundler` & `gem --version`

Comment: i think you need to downgrade you're `bundler` version or upgrade you're gems version > 2.5.0

Comment: @UdAY thank you so much when I upgrade my gems version to 2.5.2 all my problems have been solved

Answer (score 0):

You need to downgrade you're `bundler` version or upgrade you're gems version > 2.5.0. Because `bundler 2` don't support the gems version < 2.5.0