# Bundler 2 requires Ruby 2.3 or later

Tags: ruby, rubygems, fastlane

I had a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55789905/how-to-fix-bundler-2-requires-rubygems-2-5-or-later), but that question doesn't solve my problem as it hasn't been answered.

Error: `Bundler 2 requires Ruby 2.3 or later. Either install bundler 1 or update to a supported Ruby version.`

I am trying to use fastlane on a Linux machine to build Android applications. I have installed Ruby, and a few gems that was required by Fastlane, but as soon as I installed bundler, I got the error mentioned and am blocked.

Some diagnostic information that might be useful...

ruby -v : `ruby 2.6.3p62 (2019-04-16 revision 67580) [x86_64-linux]`

gem -v: `3.0.4`

bundle info bundler:

```
* bundler (2.0.2)
    Summary: The best way to manage your application's dependencies
    Homepage: https://bundler.io
    Path: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bundler-2.0.2
```

So according to what I have installed, I shouldn't be having any issues, but when I run my build through Bamboo I get the error above.

Comment: Maybe that ruby version is _too_ new for bundler? Maybe try with 2.5?